# Sum rows 1:4, 5:8, 9:12, etc

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum, excel-indirect

I have some data that is given by quarter of a year and I want to convert it to yearly data. In other words, in the yearly column, the first row must be the sum of rows 1:4 in the quarter data, the second row in yearly column the sum of rows 5:8 in the quarter data, etc. I could not find a way to do this.

[My spreadsheet is here.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rI0Nu3AmQdEwobDss_rEthvAo7EzhrFDpmjhcar33p0/edit#gid=2022331504)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your quarterly data runs A1:E4, A5:E8 etc please try in G1:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("A"&4*ROW()-3&":E"&4*ROW()))
```

copied down to suit.

Change the last `E` to `A` if your quarterly data is in ColumnA only.

In your case, since your data does not start in row1, you may need an offset to the above and, in K15 for example:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("D"&4*(ROW()-14)+11&":D"&4*(ROW()-14)+14))
```

Comment: The INDIRECT function was not known to me. That is what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Excel SUM function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sum-HP005209290.aspx).

You'd click the cell you want to hold the `sum`, then type

```
=SUM(
```

next, drag to highlight the cells you'd like to sum.

Finally, type `)` then press `Enter`.

Comment: I know how to use the SUM function. This isn't what I want to do. Please read the question again.